# Can't open *.hbs file with PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, phpstorm

I can't open `*.hbs` file with PhpStorm. But it can be opened in VS Code or Dreamweaver.

[image]

Comment: Install he Handlebars plugin from the Preference pane. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6884-handlebars-mustache

Answer (score 3):

In **Settings | Plugins**, press **Install JetBrains plugin...**, search for `Handlebars/Mustache` plugin, download and install it - this should solve the issue.
If this doesn't help, make sure that `index.hbs` or `*.hbs` pattern is not assigned to *Files opened in associated applications* file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types**